# How to Split Form entries and replace text within a cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a form that serves as an application to receive volunteer teams for my NGO. What I want to do is create a script that sends an email to the registrar upon someone completing the form. That's the easy part which I know how to do.

I want to include in that "email notification" a few key answers from some questions for the registrar to see. This I also know how to accomplish.

here is my current code that works:

```
function Team_ApplicationMailer(e) {
   var recipient = "myemail@gmail.com";
   var timestamp = e.values[0];
   var name = e.values[3];
   var country = e.values[1]
   var subject = e.values[1]+' wants to Volunteer!' ;
   var startdate = e.values[12];
   var enddate = e.values[13]
   var hyperlink = "mylink.com"
   htmlBody = '<u><strong>'+name+'</u></strong> from: <u><strong>'+country+'</strong></u>just completed the Teams Application Form for these dates: <u><strong>'+startdate+' to '+enddate+'</u></strong><br><br>Form completed on: <u><strong>'+timestamp+'</u></strong><br><br>View the Form: <a href="'+hyperlink+'">Click Here</a>';
MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, htmlBody, {htmlBody:htmlBody});
}
```

Here's the tricky part I want to add: I want to also add data found in e.values[19] and e.values[20], but these values are from either a multiple choice (e.values[19]) or checkbox (e.values[20]) and I need the values both simplified—i.e. some text deleted—and possibly split when emailed.

The two questions are basically identical. e.values[19] is "What do you want to do: 1st Priority" with some multiple-choice options. and e.values[20] is "What else do you want to do" with some checkbox options. Both questions have the same 7 choices and each choice has a long description (hence the need to shorten)

Basically I want e.values[19] which value looks like this:

optionX: (Long Description)

to look like this in the email:

What do you want to do: optionX.

I don't want the long description of the option in the "()" to be included.

For e.values[20] I want the values to look like this in the email:

What else do you want to do: optionA, optionB, optionC

INSTEAD of This:

optionA: (Long Description),optionB: (Long Description),optionC: (Long Description)

I've looked into the .replace and .split functions but don't know how to make them work together, especially for the checkbox option.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a function for this. It just removes anything inside parentheses `()`. This seems to be what you're looking for.

```
var s = e.values[19];
s = s.replace(/\([^)]*\)/g,"");
```

If you have parentheses inside parentheses, let me know, and I will have to make a quick edit.

So what's happening here.

1. It's looking for a `(`.
2. It's looking for as many characters as it can while matching a `)` at the end. This is without having a `)` inside.

   - If you had allowed a `)` inside, it would match `optionA:`**`(...), optionB: (...), optionC: (...)`**. We want to avoid this, so we do not allow `)` inside. That's what `[^)]` means.
3. The `g` flag means to match "globally", or everywhere in the string.

Comment: regular expressions are always tricky to start with. if you have used parentheses for your question only and they aren't present, then you can adapt Phil's pattern to look instead for a pair of `optionX:` and `,` or end of line

Comment: I completely understand where you're coming from. So I threw together an example that works with `String.slice()`. http://jsfiddle.net/r2Zr4/

Comment: Exactly! `s` is a string. You can insert it anywhere you'd like in the HTML body.